# Delete firebase user account by UID - Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

Does anyone know how to delete a user account by UID?

Here is my code...

component.ts

```
this.authService.deleteUser(this.selectedUID).subscribe(resData => {
    console.log(resData)
  })
```

auth.service.ts

```
deleteUser(idToken: string){
  return this.http.post<any>('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:delete?key=[my api key is entered here]', {
    idToken: idToken
  })
}
```

The error I'm getting returned by firebase is INVALID_ID_TOKEN.

Anything will help!

Answer (score 1):

To delete the user in angular,
You have to create a any server (preferable NodeJS) and user firebase-admin in your server.

You will call node js server path from your client side code i.e. angular.

Due to security reasons, Firebase doesn’t allow user deletion on client side

Comment: Have a look at the official docs. I believe I am following the steps correctly. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-delete-account